# Numpy NdArray Memoization

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix, numpy, memoization

I'm working on some fairly computational intensive calculations that deal with numpy matrices and ndarrays, and from some digging around, there are about a dozen ways **not** to implement memoization, generally full of collisions, and issues with ndarrays being mutable objects.

Has anyone come across a fairly general memoisation decorator that can handle numpy objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this package:

<s>http://packages.python.org/joblib/memory.html</s>

***2021 update***
https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Memory.html

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit instead of just posting a link?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/130885

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is my package jug:

http://packages.python.org/Jug

It is similar to joblib, but with a slightly different approach.