# Fast way to Hash Numpy objects for Caching

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Implementing a system where, when it comes to the heavy mathematical lifting, I want to do as little as possible.

I'm aware that there are issues with memoisation with numpy objects, and as such implemented a lazy-key cache to avoid the whole "Premature optimisation" argument.

```
def magic(numpyarg,intarg):
    key = str(numpyarg)+str(intarg)

    try:
        ret = self._cache[key]
        return ret
    except:
        pass

    ... here be dragons ...
    self._cache[key]=value
    return value
```

but since string conversion takes quite a while...

```
t=timeit.Timer("str(a)","import numpy;a=numpy.random.rand(10,10)")
t.timeit(number=100000)/100000 = 0.00132s/call
```

What do people suggest as being 'the better way' to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hash a large object (dataset) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806151/how-to-hash-a-large-object-dataset-in-python)

Comment: Note that `str(a)` only shows a part of the array, as would be later pointed out in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array#comment23847098_16589791

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806151/how-to-hash-a-large-object-dataset-in-python/806342#806342)... so really I guess this is a duplicate:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.rand(10, 100)
>>> b = a.view(numpy.uint8)
>>> hashlib.sha1(b).hexdigest()
'15c61fba5c969e5ed12cee619551881be908f11b'
>>> t=timeit.Timer("hashlib.sha1(a.view(numpy.uint8)).hexdigest()", 
                   "import hashlib;import numpy;a=numpy.random.rand(10,10)") 
>>> t.timeit(number=10000)/10000
2.5790500640869139e-05
```

Comment: Nice! For multidimensional arrays this gives a different hash (for the "same" array) depending on whether it's fortran or c contiguous. If that's an issue, calling `np.ascontiguousarray` should solve it.

Comment: Not sure why a known slow hash function `sha1` is chosen.  SHA-1 is OK for minimising hash collision but poor at speed.  For speed you'll need something like `murmurhash` or `xxhash` (the latter claims to be even faster).

Comment: @CongMa, thanks for the extra info. There are lots of options! But as you'll notice, this is already two orders of magnitude faster. And speed is never the _only_ concern. It's probably worth using a well-understood hash if the alternative is only a few millionths of a second faster.

Answer (score 7):

There is a package for this called [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html). Found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362781/numpy-ndarray-memoization) question.

```py
from joblib import Memory
location = './cachedir'
memory = Memory(location)

# Create caching version of magic
magic_cached = memory.cache(magic)
result = magic_cached(...)

# Or (for one-time use)
result = memory.eval(magic, ...)
```

Comment: It would be better to have a quote from those links copied over in your answer, in case these websites go offline.

Answer (score 2):

For small numpy arrays also this might be suitable:

```
tuple(map(float, a))
```

if `a` is the numpy array.

Comment: Oh yes, tuple is hashable in comparison with list!