# Hash each value in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, hash, pandas

In python, I am trying to find the quickest to hash each value in a pandas data frame.

I know any string can be hashed using:

```
hash('a string')
```

But how do I apply this function on each element of a pandas data frame?

This may be a very simple thing to do, but I have just started using python.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pass the `hash` function to `apply` on the `str` column:

```
In [37]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asds','asdds','asdsadsdas']})
df
Out[37]:
            a
0        asds
1       asdds
2  asdsadsdas
In [39]:

df['hash'] = df['a'].apply(hash)
df
Out[39]:
            a                 hash
0        asds  4065519673257264805
1       asdds -2144933431774646974
2  asdsadsdas -3091042543719078458
```

If you want to do this to every element then call `applymap`:

```
In [42]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asds','asdds','asdsadsdas'],'b':['asewer','werwer','tyutyuty']})
df
Out[42]:
            a         b
0        asds    asewer
1       asdds    werwer
2  asdsadsdas  tyutyuty
In [43]:

df.applymap(hash)
​
Out[43]:
                     a                    b
0  4065519673257264805  7631381377676870653
1 -2144933431774646974 -6124472830212927118
2 -3091042543719078458 -1784823178011532358
```

Comment: Heads-up: `hash()` does not return the same values for each run on every machine! For details see my anser below.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30144092/1864294) a heads-up: `hash()` does not return the same values for a string for each run on every machine. Depending on your use-case, you better use

```
import hashlib

def md5hash(s: str): 
    return hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() # or SHA, ...

df['a'].apply(md5hash)
# or
df.applymap(md5hash)
```

or set the [`PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED). For those wondering *why* this behaviour exists, it is [protection against malicious attackers sending keys designed to collide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/525010).

Comment: So important, thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 8):

Pandas also has a function to apply a hash function on an array or column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asds','asdds','asdsadsdas']})
df["hash"] = pd.util.hash_array(df["a"].to_numpy())
```

Comment: can this be used to generate an Int size hashcode?

Comment: Indeed, it returns an array of integers https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_array.html

Comment: those int64 are way bigger than by target int though - which is a postgresdb integer