# Weird behaviour in python with dict of lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have written a function for generating a dictionnary of lambda constant functions (it's part of a more complex function but I have simplified it to the code below):

```
def function(a):
    _interpolators = {}
    for key in a.keys():
        _interpolators[key] = lambda t: a[key]

    def _interpolate(t):
        return {key:f(t) for (key,f) in _interpolators.items()}
    return _interpolate

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    d = {"foo": 2, "bar":4}
    f = function(d)
    print(f(0)["bar"])
```

Using Python 3.5.1 on OSX El Capitan, the output of program is random. It can be `2`or `4` while I would expect to have only `4`. I don't quite understand this behaviour.

Note that the "bug" does not seem to occur with python 2.7.10 and I always get `4` when I run the program several times.

Is it some kind of bug in python 3.5.1 or did I miss something obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that in your `lambda` function which you have defined it as following :

```
lambda t: a[key]
```

You didn't used variable `t` and tried to get the `a`'s value by passing the variable `key` as the key to your dictionary. And at the next time which you attempt to use this function in you enclosing function within dictionary comprehension:

```
{key:f(t) for (key,f) in _interpolators.items()}
```

Each time that you try to get the `f(t)`, since the existence of `t` is redundant here python tries to get the `a`'s value by passing the variable `key` to it, and it has nothing to do with `t`.

And the most important point is, that you expect to python override the `key` variable because you are using `key` in your dictionary comprehension.

And since `lamda` object is a function in python and has its own local namespace, each time that it tries to return the `a[key]` it cant access the iteration variable `key` inside the comprehension so due to LEGB manner after it (`lambda`) looks for `key` in Local namespace and then Enclosing and find nothing, it looks for it in Global scope.

And since the global `key` is the last iteration variable in following part :

```
for key in a.keys():
        _interpolators[key] = lambda t: a[key]
```

The `lambda` function will use it as the `key`. And since in python 3.X the order of `dict.keys()` is randomly, the result would be randomly as well. While it's not like so in python 2.

And for getting ride of this problem you can simply change your `lambda` as following:

```
lambda t: a[t]
```

And in your code :

```
def function(a):
    _interpolators = {}
    for key in a.keys():
        _interpolators[key] = lambda t: a[t]

    def _interpolate():
        return {k:f(k) for k,f in _interpolators.items()}
    return _interpolate

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    d = {"foo": 2, "bar":4}
    f = function(d)
    print(f()["bar"])
```

Comment: @NicolasRougier Welcome, So you can tell this to community by accepting the answer.

Comment: Your function does something else, than the OP's intention was. Your `_interpolators` dictionary doesn't make any sense. Look at my solution, to see, how to do it correctly.

Comment: @Daniel This is not OP's intention, it's just an example which OP tried to explain the main problem, and what I said in my answer was a complete describe of the problem which OP is faced with, and the last suggestion was across this aim.

Comment: @Daniel Actually,I didn't care about this imaginary points which I gain with up vote and accepts, the thing is that the most complete answer should be accept by OP. And that's because  the future readers care more about accepted answer.

Comment: @Kasramvd: the OP has some functions `f[key](t)`. This is clearly something else than `f(k)`. An explanation may be as nice as possible, if it does not address the problem, its worthless. The `t` in OP's lambdas may be unused in his simple example, but not in his real problem.

Answer (score 1):

`key` in the lambda is taken from the scope of the function `function`. So it has the value of the last element in `a.keys()`. The order of keys in a dictionary is arbitrary and changes in Python 3 for each run, due to security reasons.
Make `key` a local variable of the lambda:

```
def function(a):
    _interpolators = {key: (lambda t, k=key: a[k]) for key in a}

    def _interpolate(t):
        return {key:f(t) for (key,f) in _interpolators.items()}
    return _interpolate
```

Comment: @NicolasRougier: FWIW, you can read more about this hash randomization at [hash function in Python 3.3 returns different results between sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27522626/4014959)

Comment: @Kasramvd: Daniel has explained the main problem with the OP's code in his first two sentences. However, the results of the OP's buggy code vary from run to run due to the random `PYTHONHASHSEED`  issue.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually if I was to say better, this doesn't explained the main problem and the items order is the last and least problem. it's all about functions namespaces.