# Unintuitive behavior of lambda in a cycle

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I am getting the following results in Python3

```
>>> [f() for f in ((lambda: k) for k in range(5))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is what I would expect, however I when I use list comprehension instead, I get:

```
>>> [f() for f in [(lambda: k) for k in range(5)]]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Why is that the case? It's very unintuitive to me. I thought that perhaps the function gets somehow copied, but no:

```
>>> fs = [(lambda: k) for k in range(5)]
>>> fs[0] is fs[1]
False
```

Comment: For more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554717/weird-behaviour-in-python-with-dict-of-lambda-functions/34555043#34555043

Comment: Very common Python mistake.  Each call to the lambda returns the `k` object.  By the time the range is finished, the `k` object has the value 4.