# Library `requests` getting different results unpredictably

Tags: python, python-requests

Why does this code:

```
import requests


response = requests.post('http://evds.tcmb.gov.tr/cgi-bin/famecgi', data={
    'cgi': '$ozetweb',
    'ARAVERIGRUP': 'bie_yymkpyuk.db',
    'DIL': 'UK',
    'ONDALIK': '5',
    'wfmultiple_selection': 'ZAMANSERILERI',
    'f_begdt': '07-01-2005',
    'f_enddt': '07-10-2016',
    'ZAMANSERILERI': ['TP.PYUK1', 'TP.PYUK2', 'TP.PYUK21', 'TP.PYUK22', 'TP.PYUK3', 'TP.PYUK4', 'TP.PYUK5', 'TP.PYUK6'],
    'YON': '3',
    'SUBMITDEG': 'Report',
    'GRTYPE': '1',
    'EPOSTA': 'xxx',
    'RESIMPOSTA': '***',
})

print(response.text)
```

produces different results in Python 2 (`2.7.12`) and Python 3 (`3.5.2`)? I'm using `requests==2.11.1`. Since the `requests` library supports both Python versions with the same API, I guess the result should be the same.

The expected result is the one obtained from running the code with Python 2. It works every single time. When ran with Python 3, the server sometimes returns an error, and sometimes it works. (This is the intriguing part.)

Since it works with Python 2, I figure the error must happen in the client side. Is there any caveat to how Python 3 handles encoding, or sending the data through the socket, that I should be aware of?

**EDIT:** In the comments below, a person was able to reproduce this and confirms this issue exists.

Comment: What versions of requests?

Comment: 2.11.1, editing the question! Thanks for asking.

Comment: What error do you get, a client side error or server side?

Comment: `POST` usually modifies data on server.  Why should you expect it to return the same everytime?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't, it's just the submitted data of a public form. Also, with Python 2, it returns the same, every single time. There *is* some inconsistency between Python 2 and 3 behavior here, because the server doesn't know which Python I'm using, still the response changes when I change Python version.

Comment: Could you try doing `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and then check the python2 behaviour again.  Because without that, it's not actually the same request (python2 has bytes data and python3 has str data)

Comment: Either way, the response code is 200, but the string in the body shows an error when using Python 3.

Comment: @wim: Even with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, still works with Python 2 every time.

Comment: I've checked the request headers and body, and it apparently is the same with both versions. I am wondering if this could be something in a lower level of the API.

Comment: I can reproduce, works fine with python2, does not actually work at all for me using python3.

Comment: Great, then it's not just me.

Comment: Very mysterious.  I'm interested to know the reason.

Comment: Interesting,  if you pass `data = what  you get if you print response.request.body using python2`, it works and also if you make a list of tuples in place of a dict it works every time.

Comment: Great! I'll make this work using a list of tuples then. I also reported this issue in their GitHub, so I hope they'll see this and check if it's a bug.

Comment: The body of the requests are identical as far as the encoding etc.. goes, unless you some reason the order is affecting the output I cannot see what else is different.

Comment: I think we may have a clue, run both of these http://pastebin.com/BRFfEKdE, add a `print(good.text)` and  a `print(bad.text)` at the bottom and I bet only the good will output what you want. I think the order does indeed matter, because of how the hashing works in python3  vs python2 is the reason you see the difference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in English please?  Are you saying the server cares about what order the data comes in?

Comment: Well if so, then that's a very dumb implementation.

Comment: @wim, yes,  that is what seems to be the difference, in particular `('cgi', '$ozetweb')` not being first seems to always reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't even think of that, since servers are not supposed to care about that order. I guess it's solved now. Padraic, can you write an answer so I can mark it as solved and you get the points?

Comment: Yes, this should be in answer not comments :P   Somewhat disappointed in the answer.. thought it might have been some crazy requests bug!

Comment: @jpmelos, sure, will throw something together  in a few minutes.

Comment: So was I. I scratched my head so long over this thing... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to come down to different between dicts in python2 vs python3  in relation to [Hash randomization is enabled by default](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#porting-python-code) since python3.3 and the server needing at least the *cgi* field to come first, the following can reproduce:

```
good = requests.post('http://evds.tcmb.gov.tr/cgi-bin/famecgi', data=([
    ('cgi', '$ozetweb'),
    ('ARAVERIGRUP', 'bie_yymkpyuk.db'),
    ('DIL', 'UK'),
    ('ONDALIK', '5'),
    ('wfmultiple_selection', 'ZAMANSERILERI'),
    ('f_begdt', '07-01-2005'),
    ('f_enddt', '07-10-2016'),
    ('ZAMANSERILERI',
     ['TP.PYUK1', 'TP.PYUK2', 'TP.PYUK21', 'TP.PYUK22', 'TP.PYUK3', 'TP.PYUK4', 'TP.PYUK5', 'TP.PYUK6']),
    ('YON', '3'),
    ('SUBMITDEG', 'Report'),
    ('GRTYPE', '1'),
    ('EPOSTA', 'xxx'),
    ('RESIMPOSTA', '***')]))


bad = requests.post('http://evds.tcmb.gov.tr/cgi-bin/famecgi', data=([
    ('ARAVERIGRUP', 'bie_yymkpyuk.db'),
    ('cgi', '$ozetweb'),
    ('DIL', 'UK'),
    ('wfmultiple_selection', 'ZAMANSERILERI'),
    ('ONDALIK', '5'),
    ('f_begdt', '07-01-2005'),
    ('f_enddt', '07-10-2016'),
    ('ZAMANSERILERI',
     ['TP.PYUK1', 'TP.PYUK2', 'TP.PYUK21', 'TP.PYUK22', 'TP.PYUK3', 'TP.PYUK4', 'TP.PYUK5', 'TP.PYUK6']),
    ('YON', '3'),
    ('SUBMITDEG', 'Report'),
    ('GRTYPE', '1'),
    ('EPOSTA', 'xxx'),
    ('RESIMPOSTA', '***')]))
```

Running the code above using python2:

```
In [6]: print(good.request.body)
   ...: print(bad.request.body)
   ...: 
   ...: print(len(good.text), len(bad.text))
   ...: 
cgi=%24ozetweb&ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&DIL=UK&ONDALIK=5&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&f_begdt=07-01-2005&f_enddt=07-10-2016&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&YON=3&SUBMITDEG=Report&GRTYPE=1&EPOSTA=xxx&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A
ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&cgi=%24ozetweb&DIL=UK&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&ONDALIK=5&f_begdt=07-01-2005&f_enddt=07-10-2016&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&YON=3&SUBMITDEG=Report&GRTYPE=1&EPOSTA=xxx&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A
(71299, 134)
```

And python3:

```
In [4]: print(good.request.body)
   ...: print(bad.request.body)
   ...: 
   ...: print(len(good.text), len(bad.text))
   ...: 
cgi=%24ozetweb&ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&DIL=UK&ONDALIK=5&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&f_begdt=07-01-2005&f_enddt=07-10-2016&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&YON=3&SUBMITDEG=Report&GRTYPE=1&EPOSTA=xxx&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A
ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&cgi=%24ozetweb&DIL=UK&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&ONDALIK=5&f_begdt=07-01-2005&f_enddt=07-10-2016&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&YON=3&SUBMITDEG=Report&GRTYPE=1&EPOSTA=xxx&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A
71299 134
```

Passing your dict as posted in python2:

```
In [4]: response.request.body
Out[4]: 'cgi=%24ozetweb&DIL=UK&f_enddt=07-10-2016&YON=3&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&GRTYPE=1&SUBMITDEG=Report&f_begdt=07-01-2005&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&ONDALIK=5&EPOSTA=xxx'

In [5]: len(response.text)
Out[5]: 71299
```

And the same dict in python3:

```
In [3]: response.request.body
Out[3]: 'EPOSTA=xxx&ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&DIL=UK&SUBMITDEG=Report&cgi=%24ozetweb&GRTYPE=1&f_enddt=07-10-2016&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&ONDALIK=5&f_begdt=07-01-2005&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A&YON=3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6'

In [4]: len(response.text)
Out[4]: 134
```

And running `~$ export PYTHONHASHSEED=1234` before starting another ipython2 shell:

```
In [4]: response.request.body
Out[4]: 'DIL=UK&GRTYPE=1&ARAVERIGRUP=bie_yymkpyuk.db&f_begdt=07-01-2005&RESIMPOSTA=%2A%2A%2A&ONDALIK=5&EPOSTA=xxx&YON=3&SUBMITDEG=Report&wfmultiple_selection=ZAMANSERILERI&cgi=%24ozetweb&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK1&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK2&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK21&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK22&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK3&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK4&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK5&ZAMANSERILERI=TP.PYUK6&f_enddt=07-10-2016'

In [5]: os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"]
Out[5]: '1234'
In [6]: len(response.text)
Out[6]: 134
```

You can run the code numerous times to the same end but definitely  `('cgi', '$ozetweb')` coming first is essential for the code to work, it happened to work using python3 intermittently as the order of the keys sometimes put *cgi* first. There is a bit more on the [hashing topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/2141635)