# Is it possible to generate the same id from identical lists but with different order?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists (unique elements) (mainly lists of strings).

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['c','b','a']
```

and I would like to have a function:

```
def foo_id(list)
```

where it generates an **id** based on their elements but without taking into account the order of the elements in my list.

i.e

```
foo_id(l1) == foo_id(l2)
```

Comment: Could you convert the `lists` to `sets`?

Comment: Do you care about repeating elements in your list?

Comment: The elements in the list will be unique in any case

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance but this is more a question of "How I can do that" and not "why this is happening" Therefore I don't understand why it should include any trial and error attempts. I can imagine there are bad question patterns like "Do this work for me" but in my case, I tried to formulate a minimal question with the necessary foo code in order to get a simple answer i.e "use this foo.foobar  function". In simple words, I find the downvoting a bit unfair :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate unique ids as follows.

```
import hashlib # provides many hash functions including md5, sha1, sha2, etc.

l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['c','b','a']

def genereate_id(l):
  s = str(sorted(l))    
  s_unicode = s.encode('utf-8') # hashlib requires unicode
  return hashlib.md5(s_unicode).hexdigest()

print(genereate_id(l1)) # eea457285a61f212e4bbaaf890263ab4
print(genereate_id(l2)) # eea457285a61f212e4bbaaf890263ab4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
from hashlib import blake2b

def foo_id(l):
    h = blake2b()
    h.update(str(sorted(l)).encode('ascii'))
    return h.hexdigest()

l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['c','b','a']
foo_id(l1) == foo_id(l2)
# output: True
```

> **Note**: 
>   It is not possible to directly use the Python `hash()` since in
>   executions it would give different results: this is because from
>   Python3 the `hash()` function is associated with a session
>   seed(`PYTHONHASHSEED`) for generating random numbers. Find more
>   information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/9302488).