# Why does the order of elements in python's set object change when program is ran more than once

Tags: python, set

I have this `set` and when I run this program twice the order of printing is changed

```
S = {7, "veil", 0, -29, ("x", 11), "sun", frozenset({8, 4, 7}), 913}
print(S)
```

first time output:- `{'veil', 0, -29, 'sun', 7, frozenset({8, 4, 7}), ('x', 11), 913}`

second time output:- `{0, -29, 7, frozenset({8, 4, 7}), 'veil', 913, ('x', 11), 'sun'}`

I assumed that this behaviour is because only `hashable` objects  can be added to a set and it is unordered but since a dictionary's keys are `hashable` and it is unordered then a dictionary should  show this behaviour too, but it doesn't

Why does the order of the elements change in the `set`?

Comment: A set is an unsorted list of items; so I would think the order of elements is not defined (and thus random);

Comment: @OliverMason can you see the question now I updated it?

Comment: @OliverMason why does the dictionary shows a different behaviour?

Comment: It is a direct implication of a securtiy patch explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/5378816

Comment: @RoadRunner but dictionaries are unordered , they don't show this behaviour

Comment: @VPfB Is correct, this is due to hash randomization (as explained in the linked duplicate).

Comment: @wim I read those answers and set problem is clear for me now, but since dictionarie's keys also `hashabale` but its items always shows in the order that they were added. Why does that happen?

Comment: The implementation of sets and dicts is entirely different.  Dicts preserve insertion order.

Comment: @wim as explained in here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/5378816](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708/5378816) it syas that random hashing can affect of dicts

Comment: @VPfB as you pointed in your link it says that dicts' order is affected by random hashing, but it doen't

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara  You're right. Martijn's answer is from 2014, it's now outdated/incorrect. The dicts preserving ordering was added to the language in 2018.

Comment: @wim thanks a lot it helped me the most

Comment: Thanks to everybody adding details and corrections. I did not pay attention to the dict part.

Comment: @VPfB you are mostly welcome

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara: I've updated my answer; what changed is that the implementation of `dict` was updated in Python 3.6 to be more more memory efficient. A side-effect of this change is that the `dict` type now lists keys in insertion order, irrespective of the hash value. This same change can't be applied to sets, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is an excellent answer thanks for the update.