# sets are unordered but python seems to "set a seed"

Tags: python

I know that Python sets are unordered. For example, executing this code 10 times will yield around 5 times [DR1, DR12] and five times [DR12, DR1].

```
list_of_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]
list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
list_of_list[0] = list(set(list_of_list[0]))
print(list_of_list)
```

However, when executing this code:

```
for _ in range(5):
    list_of_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]
    list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
    list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
    list_of_list[0].append("DR1")
    list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
    list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
    list_of_list[0].append("DR12")
    list_of_list[0] = list(set(list_of_list[0]))
    print(list_of_list)
```

We always get the same order for each iteration of the `for` loop but if we restart the code we might get another order (but then this other order would be repeated 5 times).

It seems that there is some sort of seed Python sets, a sort of ordered unordering the hashmaps introduce. What is the underlying explanation?

After some investigation I came up with that conclusion but I still would want someone to confirm I'm right since I'm a beginner in programming: Would that mean that Python adds a random seed to the hash computation of strings at the start of the program? I know hashes of integers don't change since there are the integer itself modulo 2**61-1 but the hash of strings does? (`print(hash("d"))` yields different values if you restart the program several times)

Comment: Well, could it mean that better to consider that the elements of a set will not always have the same order?

Comment: I guess I'm not asking for advice for practical projects but rather I'm trying to understand the uunderlying reasons why that is the case @JoseCabreraZuniga - sorry if that wasn't entirely clear in my post

Comment: This might be on purpose to force people to always consider not to use a set as an array of ordered items.

Comment: The fact that the hashing algorithm does use a random seed is already described at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522626/hash-function-in-python-3-3-returns-different-results-between-sessions. It will be consistent within a single invocations, but may change across invocations.