# how to remove duplicated elements from a list without using set()?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1,1,1,1])
b = np.array([2,2,2])
```

be two numpy arrays. Then let

```
c = [a]+[b]+[b]
```

clearly, `c` has duplicated elements `b`. Now I wish to remove one array `b` from `c` so that `c` only contains one `a` and one `b`

For removing duplicated elements in a list I usually used `set()`. However, if, this time, I do

```
set(c)
```

I would receive error like

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

In my understanding is that the `numpy.ndarray` is not hashable.

The list `c` above is just an example, in fact my `c` could be very long. So, is there any good way to remove duplicated elements from a list of numpy.array?

Thx!

---

edit: I would expect my return to be `c = [a]+[b]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is the same as the one below.
[Removing duplicates from a list of numPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751072/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-numpy-arrays)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1,1,1,1])
b = np.array([2,2,2])

arraylist = [a, b, b]
L = {array.tostring(): array for array in arraylist}
c = [v for v in L.values()]
c
```

result c:

```
[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2])]
```

Comment: same to above, the c will not be a list of numpy, right?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. yes. The above answer is using list and set and the below answer is only using numpy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
c = a.tolist() + b.tolist() + b.tolist()
```

And then

```
c = set(c)
```

Comment: I think in this way the c is no longer a list of numpy, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the minimum lines of code:

```py
list1 = [7,7,3,3,8]
list2 = []
for k in list1:
    if k not in list2:
        list2.append(k)
print(list2)  # Output: [7, 3, 8]
```