# Get the same hash value for a Pandas DataFrame each time

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to get unique hash value for a DataFrame. I obtain it out of .csv file. 
Whole point is to get the same hash each time I call hash() on it.

My idea was that I create the function

```
def _get_array_hash(arr):
    arr_hashable = arr.values
    arr_hashable.flags.writeable = False
    hash_ = hash(arr_hashable.data)
    return hash_
```

that is calling underlying numpy array, set it to immutable state and get hash of the buffer.

**INLINE UPD.**

As of 08.11.2016, this version of the function doesn't work anymore. Instead, you should use

```
hash(df.values.tobytes())
```

See comments for the [Most efficient property to hash for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array/16592241#16592241).

**END OF INLINE UPD.**

It works for regular pandas array:

```
In [12]: data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0], 'B': [1]})

In [13]: _get_array_hash(data)
Out[13]: -5522125492475424165

In [14]: _get_array_hash(data)
Out[14]: -5522125492475424165
```

But then I try to apply it to DataFrame obtained from a .csv file:

```
In [15]: fpath = 'foo/bar.csv'

In [16]: data_from_file = pd.read_csv(fpath)

In [17]: _get_array_hash(data_from_file)
Out[17]: 6997017925422497085

In [18]: _get_array_hash(data_from_file)
Out[18]: -7524466731745902730
```

Can somebody explain me, how's that possible?

I can create new DataFrame out of it, like

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame(data=data_from_file.values, 
            columns=data_from_file.columns, 
            index=data_from_file.index)
```

and it works again

```
In [25]: _get_array_hash(new_data)
Out[25]: -3546154109803008241

In [26]: _get_array_hash(new_data)
Out[26]: -3546154109803008241
```

But my goal is to preserve the same hash value for a dataframe across application launches in order to retrieve some value from cache.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/TomAugspurger/engarde/issues/3

Comment: I tried approach with getting hash value of index and columns, and str(data_frame) value. It's slow, and suffers from the same issues.

Comment: I'm interested in doing this as well - can I ask why you included "    arr_hashable.flags.writeable = False"? Would you expect the hash() function to possibly modify the array otherwise?

Comment: @MaxPower it was long time ago, so I don't remember exactly. But I think I was inspired by the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array/16592241#16592241.
I worked by then.
Now it doesn't work, but you can use `hash(a.data.tobytes())` instead, and you don't need `flags.writeable = False` anymore. See the comments to the referred answer.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `.data`, just use `hash(a.tobytes())` or `hash(df.values.tobytes())` if calling from DataFrame. 
I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 58):

As of Pandas 0.20.1 ([release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html)), you can use `pandas.util.hash_pandas_object` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html)). It returns one hash value for reach row of the dataframe (and works on series etc. too).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar', 42], size=(3,4))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

print(df)
#      0    1   2    3
# 0   42  foo  42   42
# 1  foo  foo  42  bar
# 2   42   42  42   42

from pandas.util import hash_pandas_object
h = hash_pandas_object(df)

print(h)
# 0     5559921529589760079
# 1    16825627446701693880
# 2     7171023939017372657
# dtype: uint64
```

If you want an overall hash, consider the following:

```
int(hashlib.sha256(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, index=True).values).hexdigest(), 16)
```

- [`hashlib.sha256()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.sha256)
- [`hash.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest)

Comment: Not 100%, but likely `hashlib.sha256(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, index=True).values).hexdigest()` will be less collisioney than `.sum()`.

Comment: @mathtick indeed, otherwise reordering rows gives the same hash.

Comment: The problem with `hash_pandas_object` is that is not serializable, due to circular dependencies, see here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35097 and here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/374

Comment: If the column names are different will they return different values?

Comment: @GrantCulp `hash_pandas_object` does not hash the columns names: the same data with different columns will result in the same hash. To avoid this you could hash `df.reset_index().T` instead of `df`, or add `df.columns.values.tobytes()` to the hash.

Answer (score 18):

[Joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.hash.html) provides a hashing function optimized for objects containing numpy arrays (e.g. pandas dataframes).

```
import joblib
joblib.hash(df)
```

Comment: This does not work for me! (df1 == df2).all() is True, but hashes are different.

Comment: @JulianWgs Do you have an example? For comparing two Series, if their name field is different, their hashes end up being different while their values are the same, but I couldn't replicate it for any DataFrame.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem: check if a dataframe is changed and I solved it by hashing the msgpack serialization string. This seems stable among different reloading the same data.

```
import pandas as pd
import hashlib
DATA_FILE = 'data.json'

data1 = pd.read_json(DATA_FILE)
data2 = pd.read_json(DATA_FILE)

assert hashlib.md5(data1.to_msgpack()).hexdigest() == hashlib.md5(data2.to_msgpack()).hexdigest()
assert hashlib.md5(data1.values.tobytes()).hexdigest() != hashlib.md5(data2.values.tobytes()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: I found `.to_msgpack()` stable in Python 3.6 but not in 3.5 (not sure why, might have something to do with dictionaries being ordered in Python 3.6+).  Just keep it simple and to `.to_csv().encode('utf-8')` instead.

Comment: Keeping ostrokach's (above) comment in mind: this solution has of the out-of-the-box advantage of dealing with unhashable dataframe-elements (in contrast with `pd.util.hash_pandas_object`).

Comment: As of I think pandas 1.0, `df.to_msgpack()` is deprecated. The recommended alternative to `.to_msgpack()` in the pandas documentation is pyarrow, but that opens up a whole new can of worms

Comment: Also `data1.values.tobytes()` might return deterministic values for numeric dataframe contents, but if you have string values in your dataframe, you'll get a different bytestring for different python sessions. Might match within the same python session though

Comment: Unfortunately `.values` fails to capture the uniqueness of a DataFrame, with `print(hashlib.md5(pd.DataFrame({'X': []}).values.tobytes()).hexdigest())` and `print(hashlib.md5(pd.DataFrame({'Y': []}).values.tobytes()).hexdigest())` producing the same hash.

Comment: [`df.to_msgpack()` was deprecated in 2019](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27722).

Answer (score 2):

This function seems to work fine:

```
from hashlib import sha256
def hash_df(df):
    s = str(df.columns) + str(df.index) + str(df.values)
    return sha256(s.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30291028)

Comment: Thank you for your advice
I made a [separate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890648/why-dont-we-get-the-same-hash-value-with-hashlib-sha256-when-passing-the-exact)