# How to get sha256().hexdigest() in dataframe

Tags: python

I have read the xlsx sheet and used `sha256().hexdigest()` in this code, but getting errors:

```
for file in files_to_be_updated:
    print("file",source_path + '/' + file)
    file_bytes = pd.read_excel(source_path + '/' + file , index=False,encode="utf-8")
    source_hash = sha256(file_bytes).hexdigest()
    print(source_hash)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/krishna/PycharmProjects/projcts/ispp-funds-platform-data-mart/test5.py", line 34, in <module>
    source_hash = sha256(file_bytes).hexdigest()
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

Comment: please reformat your code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to feed a pandas dateframe into the sha256 constructor which expects a bytes like object.

Use `hash_pandas_object` from `pandas.util` instead if you want a hash for the dataframe, like this:

```
sha256(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(file_bytes).values).hexdigest()
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47800021/7982679)