# Why don't we get the same hash value with hashlib.sha256 when passing the exact same values from two different pd dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hash, sha256, hashlib

Why don't we get the same hash value with hashlib.sha256 when passing the exact same values from two different pd dataframes?
Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_df():
    np.random.seed(42)
    arr = np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar', 42], size=(3,4))
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
    df.columns = list('abcd')
    df.index = list('efg')
    return df

from hashlib import sha256
def hash_df(df):
    s = str(df.columns) + str(df.index) + str(df.values)
    return sha256(s.encode()).hexdigest()

print(generate_df())
#      a    b   c    d
# e   42  foo  42   42
# f  foo  foo  42  bar
# g   42   42  42   42

df1 = generate_df()
df2 = generate_df()
print("df1 hash: ", hash_df(df1))
print("df2 hash: ", hash_df(df2))
# df1 hash:  eb02e26c4b0d3092d916e3ab6098ff77bfa23477a220c44efd290bed47409513
# df2 hash:  eb02e26c4b0d3092d916e3ab6098ff77bfa23477a220c44efd290bed47409513

### now that is very weird:
print("df1.values hash: ", sha256(df1.values).hexdigest())
print("df2.values hash: ", sha256(df2.values).hexdigest())
# df1.values hash:  d155834807ed3907bcdd1ec55b921dd47073994b8d885257bfb23ae379dd1b9a
# df2.values hash:  bbdbd29960c72e2fd2c7dc3f60d73ed71d48619fda6917ac896b94baf7c9de9f

print(df1.values==df2.values)
# [[ True  True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True  True]]
```

Is there an explanation?
I thought that hashing this way depended only on the value, not on the "container".

Comment: Your method of hashing differs. In `hash_df` you convert to a string first. You hash the actual array objects (which are separate objects with different ids) in the second case. `sha256(str(df1.values).encode()).hexdigest() == sha256(str(df2.values).encode()).hexdigest()` is true which is as expected.