# Pandas DataFrame Hash Values Differ Between Unix and Windows

Tags: python, pandas, hash, operating-system, hashlib

I've noticed that hash values created from Pandas DataFrames change depending whether the below snippet is executed on Unix or Windows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                          columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

hashvalue_new = hashlib.md5(df.values.flatten().data).hexdigest()
print(hashvalue_new)
```

The above code prints `d0ecb84da86002807de1635ede730f0a` on Windows machines and `586962852295d584ec08e7214393f8b2` on Unix machines. Can someone more knowledgeable (or smarter) than me explain to me why this is happening and suggest a way to create a consistent hash value across platforms? I'm running Python 3.8.5 and pandas 1.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT January 16th

#### Why is this happening?

Following some further digging I'm now fairly certain I understand the issue. The data type (dtype) of Numpy's integers is the operating system's `C` `long` type. On Windows this defaults to a 32-bit integer, while on linux/unix it defaults to a 64-bit integer. [This has been discussed elsewhere on Stackoverflow in much more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine)

#### How to create consistent hash values across platforms?

##### Solution 1 (Original)

I'm able to achieve consistent results by relying on `pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`, as suggested elsewhere [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567401/get-the-same-hash-value-for-a-pandas-dataframe-each-time). In full my solution looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

hashvalue_new = hashlib.md5(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, index=True).values).hexdigest()
```

Which consistently gives me `9762ced20d27292712e6a2065b6d6226` across operating systems.

##### Solution 2

One can force the underlying numpy array to by `dtype` `int64`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
     dtype="int64"), 
     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

hashvalue_new = hashlib.md5(df.values.flatten().data).hexdigest()
```

Which consistently gives me `586962852295d584ec08e7214393f8b2` across operating systems.