# What is a perfect hash function to combine two int hash keys

Tags: math, hash, hash-function

let say i have a two integer hash keys and I want to combine them into a product hash key that is unique to the two hashes and sensitive to the order.

For example:

```
hashKey(3,2) != hashKey(2,3)
```

There must be a good mathematical way to achieve this. My math is pretty rusty. any help in reading material or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: This should give you the answer - [Hash Value for 3D Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951502/hash-value-for-3d-vector/31953012#31953012)

Comment: this is more or less equivalent to a normal hash code implementation of string.

Comment: It does sound like the [Hash Value for 3D Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951502/hash-value-for-3d-vector/31953012#31953012)

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to use the fact that the prime factorization of integers is unique: there's a 1-to-1 mapping between integer pairs (x,y) and numbers of the form 2<sup>x</sup>3<sup>y</sup>.

Since this is homework, I'll leave figuring out what to do with negative integers as an exercise for the reader :)