# Python - What is the fastest way to make a numpy.ndarray hashable?

Tags: python, numpy, hashable

Right now I'm using x.tostring() but I'm looking for something faster.

Comment: If there are no duplicates in the set of your arrays, you can use `id(x)`.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Unfortunately there are duplicates.

Comment: If you have large arrays and there are not too many of them, you may be better off with `np.searchsorted` instead of hashing, despite the log(N) overhead.

Comment: I assume your array is numeric. Perhaps you can calculate the sum of all elements and use it as a hash. If two sums are different, then the arrays are different, too. If the sums are equal, you can compare `.tostring()`s.

Comment: `tostring` is just a bytestring copy of the data buffer. I.e. the whole array without the shape, strides attributes.  So fetching it is fast, but as a hash it might be way too big.  But it may be the only way to distinguish two arrays that differ by only one byte.  It won't distinguish views.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array.