# Using scalar ndarrays as keys

Tags: numpy

This works

```
range(50)[np.asarray(10)]
```

This works

```
{}.get(50)
```

This doesn't because of `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

```
{}.get(np.asarray(50))
```

Is there a reason why `__hash__` isn't implemented for this case?

Comment: If you want to do this practically, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array But this is not an answer to your question, why?

Comment: `hash` isn't implemented for `list` either (nor `dict`).  It is implemented for immutable `tuple`.  That's true even for `[50]`.  The `key` for a dictionary has to be immutable.  The index for an array or list can be a mutable number.  As a rule `scalar ndarrays` aren't that useful, except as a byproduct of a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries require their keys to implement both `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods, and Python's data model requires that:

1. The hash of an object does not change during its lifetime
2. If `x == y` then `hash(x) == hash(y)`

Numpy's `ndarray` class overrides `__eq__` to support elementwise comparison and broadcasting. This means that for numpy arrays `x` and `y`, `x == y` is not a boolean but another array. This in itself probably rules out `ndarray`s functioning correctly as dictionary keys.

Even ignoring this quirk of `ndarray.__eq__`, it would be tricky to come up with a (useful) implementation of `ndarray.__hash__`. Since the data in a numpy array is mutable, we could not use that data to calculate `__hash__` without violating the requirement that the hash of an object does not change during its lifetime.

There is nothing wrong with defining `__hash__` for mutable objects provided that the hash itself does not change during the object's lifetime. Similarly, dictionary keys can be mutable provided they implement `__hash__` and the hash is immutable. E.g. simple user-defined classes are mutable but can still be used as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 2):

This `scalar array` is regular array with a 0d shape.  Otherwise there's nothing unique about it.

```
In [46]: x=np.array(10)
In [47]: x
Out[47]: array(10)
In [48]: x[...]=100
In [49]: x
Out[49]: array(100)
```

You have to extract the number from the array:

```
In [53]: {}.get(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-19202767b220> in <module>()
----> 1 {}.get(x)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
In [54]: {}.get(x.item())
In [58]: {}.get(x[()])
```

Looking at the `hash` methods

```
In [65]: x.__hash__         # None
In [66]: x.item().__hash__
Out[66]: <method-wrapper '__hash__' of int object at 0x84f2270>
In [67]: x[()].__hash__
Out[67]: <method-wrapper '__hash__' of numpy.int32 object at 0xaaab42b0>
```