# python: bookkeeping dependencies in cached attributes that might change

Tags: python, oop, caching

I have a class A with three attributes a,b,c, where a is calculated from b and c (but this is expensive). Moreover, attributes b and c are likely to change over times. I want to make sure that:

1. a is cached once it is calculated and then reproduced from cache
2. if b or c change then the next time a is needed it must be recomputed to reflect the change

the following code seems to work:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self._a = None
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

    @property
    def a(self):
        if is None:
            self.update_a()
        return self._a

    def update_a(self):
        """
        compute a from b and c
        """
        print('this is expensive')
        self._a = self.b + 2*self.c

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        self._a = None #make sure a is recalculated before its next use

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self._c = value
        self._a = None #make sure a is recalculated before its next use
```

however this approach does not seem very good for many reasons:

1. the setters of b and c needs to know about a
2. it becomes a mess to write and maintain if the dependency-tree grows larger
3. it might not be apparent in the code of update_a what its dependencies are
4. it leads to a lot of code duplication

Is there an abstract way to achieve this that does not require me to do all the bookkeeping myself?
Ideally, I would like to have some sort of decorator which tells the property what its dependencies are so that all the bookkeeping happens under the hood.

I would like to write:

```
@cached_property_depends_on('b', 'c')
def a(self):
    return self.b+2*self.c
```

or something like that.

**EDIT:** I would prefer solutions that do not require that the values assigned to a,b,c be immutable. I am mostly interested in np.arrays and lists but I would like the code to be reusable in many different situations without having to worry about mutability issues.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `functools.lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from operator import attrgetter

def cached_property_depends_on(*args):
    attrs = attrgetter(*args)
    def decorator(func):
        _cache = lru_cache(maxsize=None)(lambda self, _: func(self))
        def _with_tracked(self):
            return _cache(self, attrs(self))
        return property(_with_tracked, doc=func.__doc__)
    return decorator
```

The idea is to retrieve the values of tracked attributes each time the property is accessed, pass them to the memoizing callable, but ignore them during the actual call.

Given a minimal implementation of the class:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self._c = value

    @cached_property_depends_on('b', 'c')
    def a(self):
        print('Recomputing a')
        return self.b + 2 * self.c
```

```
a = A(1, 1)
print(a.a)
print(a.a)
a.b = 3
print(a.a)
print(a.a)
a.c = 4
print(a.a)
print(a.a)
```

outputs

```
Recomputing a
3
3
Recomputing a
5
5
Recomputing a
11
11
```

Comment: I like this approach but it only works if the values stored in b and c are hashable. In my example many attributes are lists or np.arrays so this would not work directly.

Comment: @TashiWalde maybe you should add a note about that in your question. In that case I would probably check the types of attributes inside `cached_property_depends_on` and convert unhashable objects to something hashable. [Here are your options for numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589791/2301450).

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, a dependency management system like this is easy enough to implement - if you're familiar with [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and [metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python).

Our implementation needs 4 things:

1. A new type of `property` that knows which other properties depend on it. When this property's value changes, it will notify all properties that depend on it that they have to re-calculate their value. We'll call this class `DependencyProperty`.
2. Another type of `DependencyProperty` that caches the value computed by its getter function. We'll call this `DependentProperty`.
3. A metaclass `DependencyMeta` that connects all the DependentProperties to the correct DependencyProperties.
4. A function decorator `@cached_dependent_property` that turns a getter function into a `DependentProperty`.

This is the implementation:

```
_sentinel = object()


class DependencyProperty(property):
    """
    A property that invalidates its dependencies' values when its value changes
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.dependent_properties = set()

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # if the value stayed the same, do nothing
        try:
            if self.__get__(instance) is value:
                return
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        # set the new value
        super().__set__(instance, value)

        # invalidate all dependencies' values
        for prop in self.dependent_properties:
            prop.cached_value = _sentinel

    @classmethod
    def new_for_name(cls, name):
        name = '_{}'.format(name)

        def getter(instance, owner=None):
            return getattr(instance, name)

        def setter(instance, value):
            setattr(instance, name, value)

        return cls(getter, setter)


class DependentProperty(DependencyProperty):
    """
    A property whose getter function depends on the values of other properties and
    caches the value computed by the (expensive) getter function.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.cached_value = _sentinel

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if self.cached_value is _sentinel:
            self.cached_value = super().__get__(instance, owner)

        return self.cached_value


def cached_dependent_property(*dependencies):
    """
    Method decorator that creates a DependentProperty
    """
    def deco(func):
        prop = DependentProperty(func)
        # we'll temporarily store the names of the dependencies.
        # The metaclass will fix this later.
        prop.dependent_properties = dependencies
        return prop
    return deco


class DependencyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs)

        # first, find all dependencies. At this point, we only know their names.
        dependency_map = {}
        dependencies = set()
        for attr_name, attr in vars(cls).items():
            if isinstance(attr, DependencyProperty):
                dependency_map[attr] = attr.dependent_properties
                dependencies.update(attr.dependent_properties)
                attr.dependent_properties = set()

        # now convert all of them to DependencyProperties, if they aren't
        for prop_name in dependencies:
            prop = getattr(cls, prop_name, None)
            if not isinstance(prop, DependencyProperty):
                if prop is None:
                    # it's not even a property, just a normal instance attribute
                    prop = DependencyProperty.new_for_name(prop_name)
                else:
                    # it's a normal property
                    prop = DependencyProperty(prop.fget, prop.fset, prop.fdel)
                setattr(cls, prop_name, prop)

        # finally, inject the property objects into each other's dependent_properties attribute
        for prop, dependency_names in dependency_map.items():
            for dependency_name in dependency_names:
                dependency = getattr(cls, dependency_name)
                dependency.dependent_properties.add(prop)

        return cls
```

---

And finally, some proof that it actually works:

```
class A(metaclass=DependencyMeta):
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value + 10

    @cached_dependent_property('b', 'c')
    def a(self):
        print('doing expensive calculations')
        return self.b + 2*self.c


obj = A(1, 4)
print('b = {}, c = {}'.format(obj.b, obj.c))
print('a =', obj.a)
print('a =', obj.a) # this shouldn't print "doing expensive calculations"
obj.b = 0
print('b = {}, c = {}'.format(obj.b, obj.c))
print('a =', obj.a) # this should print "doing expensive calculations"
```

Comment: I found this to be a really interesting solution, thank you. When playing around with this, I found that if you define another `cached_dependent_property`, call it `d` that depends on `'a'`, and if you define `_b` and `_c` as class variables and don't pass them into `__init__` so that the setters of `b` and `c` aren't called before referencing `a`, then `a`'s cached value is actually the `DependentProperty` itself and `obj.a` will return something like `<__main__.DependentProperty object at 0x7f23e625cdc0>` until the setter of `b` or `c` is called. Do you know why this is?