# How to generate a Hash or checksum value on Python Dataframe (created from a fixed width file)?

Tags: python, pandas, hash

I have 2 fixed width files like below (only change is Date value starting at position 14).

**sample_hash1.txt**

```
GOKULKRISHNA 04/17/2018
ABCDEFGHIJKL 04/17/2018
111111111111 04/17/2018
```

**sample_hash2.txt**

```
GOKULKRISHNA 04/16/2018
ABCDEFGHIJKL 04/16/2018
111111111111 04/16/2018
```

Using pandas read_fwf I am reading this file and creating a Dataframe by excluding the Date value and loading only the first 13 characters. My dataframe looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_fwf("sample_hash1.txt", colspecs=[(0,13)])
df2 = pd.read_fwf("sample_hash2.txt", colspecs=[(0,13)])
```

**df1**

```
   GOKULKRISHNA
0  ABCDEFGHIJKL
1  111111111111
...
```

**df2**

```
   GOKULKRISHNA
0  ABCDEFGHIJKL
1  111111111111
...
```

Now I am trying to generate a hash value on each Dataframe, but the hash is different for df1 and df2. I'm not sure what's wrong with this. Can someone throw some light on this please? I have to identify if there is any change in data between the files (excluding the Date columns).

```
print(hash(df1.values.tostring()))
-3571422965125408226

print(hash(df2.values.tostring()))
5039867957859242153
```

I am loading these files into a table (each full file is around 2 GB size). Every time we are receiving full files from source. Sometimes there is no change in the data (excluding the last column, Date). My idea is to reject such files. If I can generate a hash on the file and store it somewhere (in a table) next time I can compare the new file hash value with the stored hash. I thought this is the right approach but I got stuck with hash generation.

I checked this post
[Most efficient property to hash for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array)
but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The hash will be different for different object. Both dataframe are not the same. Try `df1.values.tostring() == df2.values.tostring()`, it should be false. If you want to have the same hash, you need to remove the data in the values before taking the hash.

Comment: yes it is False. Is there any other way i can geneate a unique code based on the data in the file? (excluding some part of the data)

Comment: you can try: `hash(df1[:-1].values.tostring())` to remove the last column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient property to hash for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array)

Comment: @TwistedSim last column is not in the dataframe anyway. i am loading first 13 characters only

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. Can you show the result of `df1.values.tostring()` and `df2.values.tostring()`

Comment: @jdehesa how come it is duplicate ? i am trying generate hash on a file excluding some of the data from file

Comment: @TwistedSim >>> df1.values.tostring()
b'\xb0=\xdb\xdbK\x7f\x00\x00\xf0=\xdb\xdbK\x7f\x00\x00'
>>> df2.values.tostring()
b'pf\xdb\xdbK\x7f\x00\x00\xb0f\xdb\xdbK\x7f\x00\x00'

Comment: Try to use: `df1.values.astype(str).str`. you need to get a string representation of your data which is the same for both. `tostring()` output a "console friendly format" which might be different with both output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string representation dataframe.

```
import hashlib

print(hashlib.sha256(df1.to_json().encode()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha256(df2.to_json().encode()).hexdigest())
```

or

```
print(hashlib.sha256(df1.to_csv().encode()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha256(df2.to_csv().encode()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Awesome. This is working. But i think hash generation will be slow on big files ?

Comment: Do you know why running the example in different run it give different hash ?

Do you know how to get the same hash for the same dataframe during different run of the code ?

Comment: This method is slow.

Answer (score 25):

You can now use `pd.util.hash_pandas_object`

```
hashlib.sha1(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df).values).hexdigest()
```

For a dataframe with 50 million rows, this method took me 10 seconds versus over a minute for the to_json() method.

Comment: how would you return a single hash for the entire dataframe though?

Comment: This answer worked well for me. `pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df)` on it's own returned a series (I believe it is the length of the number of rows in the dataframe), but using the full answer provided (putting inside hashlib.sha1(...) resulted in a single hash for the dataframe for me
(`hashlib.sha1(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df).values).hexdigest() `)

Comment: But this works only for the "content" of the dataframe and not its meta data like column and row names.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here do forget the column names (column index) of a dataframe. The `pd.util.hash_pandas_object()` create a series of hash values for each row of a dataframe including it's index (the row name). But the name of columns doesn't matter as you can see here:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> from pandas import util
>>> util.hash_pandas_object(DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]}))
0     580038878669277522
1    2529894495349307502
2    4389717532997776129
dtype: uint64
>>> util.hash_pandas_object(DataFrame({'Foo': [1,2,3], 'Bar': [4,5,6]}))
0     580038878669277522
1    2529894495349307502
2    4389717532997776129
dtype: uint64
```

My solution

```
df = DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})

hash = pandas.util.hash_pandas_object(df)

# append hash of the columns
hash = pandas.concat(
    [hash, pandas.util.hash_pandas_object(df.columns)]
)

# hash the series of hashes
hash = hashlib.sha1(hash.values).hexdigest()

print(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers - simple and fast checksum:

`checksum = pandas.util.hash_pandas_object(df).sum()`