# How does np.ndarray.tobytes() work for dtype "object"?

Tags: python, numpy

I encountered a strange behavior of [`np.ndarray.tobytes()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) that makes me doubt that it is working deterministically, at least for arrays of `dtype=object`.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array([1,[2]]).dtype)
# => object
print(np.array([1,[2]]).tobytes())
# => b'0h\xa3\t\x01\x00\x00\x00H{!-\x01\x00\x00\x00'
print(np.array([1,[2]]).tobytes())
# => b'0h\xa3\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\x88\x9d)-\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

In the sample code, a list of mixed python objects (`[1, [2]]`) is first converted to a numpy array, and then transformed to a byte sequence using `tobytes()`.

Why do the resulting byte-representations differ for repeated instantiations of the same data? The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) just states that it converts an `ndarray` to raw python bytes, but it does not refer to any limitations. So far, I observed this just for `dtype=object`. Numeric arrays always yield the same byte sequence:

```
np.random.seed(42); print(np.random.rand(3).tobytes())
# b'\xecQ_\x1ew\xf8\xd7?T\xd6\xbbh@l\xee?Qg\x1e\x8f~l\xe7?'
np.random.seed(42); print(np.random.rand(3).tobytes())
# b'\xecQ_\x1ew\xf8\xd7?T\xd6\xbbh@l\xee?Qg\x1e\x8f~l\xe7?'
```

Have I missed an elementar thing about python's/numpy's memory architecture? I tested with numpy version 1.17.2 on a Mac.

---

**Context**: I encountered this problem when trying to [compute a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791) for arbitrary data structures. I hoped that I can rely on the basic serialization capabilities of `tobytes()`, but this appears to be a wrong premise. I know that `pickle` is the standard for serialization in python, but since I don't require portability and my data structures only contain numbers, I first sought help with numpy.

Comment: I am not able to offer any advice other than: the same thing happens on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I think it depends on the layout of objects in memory. As you know, the amount of memory an object needs to be created might not be equal to the sum of memory allocated to its attributes (the offset thing). Thus the serialization will be different. If you create the same array in 'F' order you will get a different byte string.

Comment: Why do you need to use `np.ndarray.tobytes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of dtype `object` stores pointers to the objects it contains. In CPython, this corresponds to the `id`. Every time you create a new list, it will be allocated at a new memory address. However, small integers are interned, so `1` will reference the same integer object every time.

You can see exactly how this works by checking the IDs of some sample objects:

```py
>>> x = np.array([1, [2]])
>>> x.tobytes()
b'\x90\x91\x04a\xfb\x7f\x00\x00\xc8[J\xaa+\x02\x00\x00'
>>> id(x[0])
140717641208208
>>> id(1)                             # Small integers are interned
140717641208208
>>> id(x[0]).to_bytes(8, 'little')    # Checks out as the first 8 bytes
b'\x90\x91\x04a\xfb\x7f\x00\x00'
>>> id(x[1]).to_bytes(8, 'little')    # Checks out as the last 8 bytes
b'\xc8[J\xaa+\x02\x00\x00'
```

As you can see, it is quite deterministic, but serializes information that is essentially useless to you. The operation is the same for numeric arrays as for object arrays: it returns a view or copy of the underlying buffer. The contents of the buffer is what is throwing you off.

Since you mentioned that you are computing hashes, keep in mind that there is a reason that python lists are unhashable. You can have lists that are equal at one time and different at another. Using IDs is generally not a good idea for an effective hash.

Comment: Wow. This was very illuminating. Thanks! Because the inner list `[2]` is created every time I instantiated the array, its `id` changed and, accordingly, the result of `tobytes()`. And because an array of dtype "object" only stores pointers, `tobytes()` just serializes these, and not the content they are pointing at.

Comment: Therefore, `ndarray.tobytes()` is totally not suitable for my needs. To create a hash for my data, I will therefore go with pickle.