# Pandas dataframe: drop_duplicates after converting to str compares truncated strings, not actual contents

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, drop-duplicates

I tried the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855963), and it appears that the conversion to string before dropping duplicates results in the *truncated* representation being compared. It seems to me that the `dataframe.astype(str)` already has this truncation. How do I stop this from happening?

What I have tried:

The following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((100,100))
B = np.zeros((100,100))
A[50][50] = 1
B[50][51] = 1

data = [[A, 0], [B, 0]]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe2 = dataframe.astype(str).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

results in `dataframe2` being an empty dataframe, whereas this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

C = np.zeros((2,2))
D = np.zeros((2,2))
C[0][0] = 1
D[1][1] = 1
data = [[C, 0], [D, 0]]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe2 = dataframe.astype(str).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

gives `dataframe2` being the same as `dataframe`. I would expect this to be the result in the first case too.

I also tried adding `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(np.array)` can be lossy.

```
>>> print(A)
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>>> print(B)
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

They're the same!

Have a look at [How do I print the full NumPy array, without truncation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1987694/4518341)

Or there may be more efficient ways to get an array into hashable form. For example have a look at [Most efficient property to hash for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589791/4518341) or [Fast way to Hash Numpy objects for Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386694/4518341)