# Why is md5 hashing so much faster on strings than on numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, numpy, hash, md5

In python/numpy, I have a 10,000x10,000 array named `random_matrix`.  I use md5 to compute the hash for `str(random_matrix)` and for `random_matrix` itself.  It takes 0.00754404067993 seconds on the string version, and 1.6968960762 on the numpy array version.  When I make it into a 20,000x20,000 array, it takes 0.0778470039368 on the string version and 60.641119957 seconds on the numpy array version.  Why is this?  Do numpy arrays take up a lot more memory than strings?  Also, if I want to make filenames identified by these matrices, is converting to a string before computing hashes a good idea, or are there some drawbacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`str(random_matrix)` will not include all of the matrix due to numpy's eliding things with "...":

```
>>> x = np.ones((1000, 1000))
>>> print str(x)
[[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
```

So when you hash `str(random_matrix)`, you aren't really hashing all the data.

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589791/most-efficient-property-to-hash-for-numpy-array) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806151/how-to-hash-a-large-object-dataset-in-python) about how to hash numpy arrays.