# Get rid of for loop and use numpy for vectorizing iterated hashing

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, hashlib

In this assignment, we have to iteratively run data through a SHA256 algorithm replacing a number (X) with the final goal of finding a SHA256 Hash that has 11 zeroes in the beginning.

So here is the code I came up with:

```
for x in range(8388608000000):
    hash = hashlib.sha256((str(bn) + str(x) + str(d)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    if hash.find("00000000000", 0, 11) > -1:
        print(x)
        print(hash)
```

This works, but it's too slow in python. Apparently hashlib is compiled but jumping in and out because of the for loop makes things slow. I allready made multiprocessing work but that just doesn't cut it. Is there a way of getting rid of the for loop and using numpy instead somehow in this case?

1. Approach:

- Create large array with numpy.arange
- using numpy.nditer instead of x within hashlib function
- writing calculated hashes into another array
- checking if hashes exist for required conditions, printing these
- iterating the process with a for loop

2. Approach: I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806151/how-to-hash-a-large-object-dataset-in-python) for a similar problem although I do not fully understand what it means. Could it be useful in my case?

Comment: I doubt that the for-loop is (relatively) slow here: replace the sha256 calculation with a simple calculation (e.g. a sqrt or even a squaring of x, and run it again (probably want to compare with a much smaller range than 8388608000000); include a (different) if statement for completeness sake. You'll find a notable difference in timings, indicating the sha256 calculation is what's really slowing things down. As it should, since it used to be that passwords and keys were hashed/calculated with sha256.

Comment: Given that there exists bitcoin farms, you shouldn't be surprised this method takes a long time.

Comment: `nditer` is  not a speed tool; it doesn't compile your `hashlib` call or pass multiple values to it at once.  `numpy` speed depends on using the compiled whole-array methods of numpy; it can't be used if the core calculation is a function that only takes one value at a time.

Comment: Can I somehow run this on the GPU then? Numba and @jit does not work unfortunately...

Comment: Python's hashlib will not work on a GPU. You should find a custom implementation.